# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.10 broken display with extension

Tags: virtualbox, google-chrome, 16.10

I installed chrome on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10 64bit on a Virtualbox VM, through google's website (https://www.google.com/chrome/), not from ubuntu software.

It works fine just like that, but whenever I install an extension (I tried HTTPS Everywhere by EFF), the extension dropdown menu would just blank out, and when I restarted chrome, it only displays artifacts like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyxhx.png)

I tried restoring the VM to the first snapshot, and redid the steps, same results.

I'm not sure if this is an ubuntu-chrome issue in general or only when in a VM, I've never tried 16.10 natively installed.

VM specs:

```
RAM - 2GB
Processors - 4
3D Acceleration enabled, 128MB Video Memory (max in virtualbox)
```

The host system is Windows 10 Home on an Asus ROG, running Virtualbox 5.1.10 r112026 (Qt5.6.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue that it is repeated every release:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15332
- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15876

and maybe

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15417
- https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/X11Guest3D

Solution, remove 3D acceleration :)

IMO: I think that I never seen VirtualBox working properly with 3D enabled.